# Spring with ehcache - @Cacheable method does not cache

Tags: spring, ehcache

When I call for the method I annotate with `@Cacheable("myTest")`, I know the cache is not being utilized because I did a print inside the method and it should not be printed if cache is used.

In the log, I know the cache is being initialized

```
DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryStore - Initialized net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryStore for myTest
```

I should mention the way to call the method is regular Java `new MyCacheObject().cacheMethod("key");` instead of using the Spring bean. Will the cache work in this way?

Comment: Did you enable the cache with `@EnableCaching`? Anyway, add more details about your configurations and project structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I should mention the way to call the method is regular Java `new
>   MyCacheObject().cacheMethod("key");` instead of using the Spring bean.
>   Will the cache work in this way?

Spring should be able to manage your object life cycle in order to create the required proxy that adds the caching behavior. So, this approach won't work. If you can't let the spring create the beans for you, the only option is to do the cache inspection manually in `cacheMethod` and implement the typical *get-if-not-found-then-proceed-and-put-eventually* workflow.

Comment: Thank you. You're right. I modified the code to use the spring managed beans and it's working as expected.